# Visual Studio Reporting Service Reports 2008

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to generate a report that has 2 lines per record(or row) returned by the query. Simply the first row will hold certain fields but before it returns the next row/record..it generates a subrow as you may call it that holds an additional field. Is this possible? I have another idea of doing this and it would be to just add the extra field on the end of the row and wrap the row to fit on the page thus making it appear 2 lines per record/row returned.

I'm a total noob when it comes to using tablix and these reports so details would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the report designer, right-click on the detail row header (the gray area, should have 3 horizontal lines), and select Insert Row -> Inside Group (either above or below, depending on where you want the row).  [image: SSRS Row Insertion]

This will add a new row to the current group, with the current group being your detail rows.  You can then add fields and text to the second row, and both will show up for each dataset record when the report is run.

Comment: Awesome Solution! It works :) Now i got to figure out how to debug a report if possible. Is there a way to remove the extra cells added after the above solution is applied? I only need the first 2 cells, leaving 3 empty cells on the rendered reports. Be nice to remove the border around the cells of this specific row so that it has a more distinct view from the user.

Comment: You can leave any cells blank to have them not show up on the rendered report.  Also, the border is defaulted in SSRS (I find it a pain), but you can select your cells, go to the Properties window (F4), expand BorderStyle, and switch the Default to None.

Comment: Sweet! Learned alot today :) Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem!  If this answered your question, would you mind marking it as the answer?